Nuxt Cannot stringify arbitrary non-POJOs for simple object
I've been through a few of these question on SO but I can't figure out the gist.  Why does this simple class get an error:
500 Cannot stringify arbitrary non-POJOs

This is a pretty simple object
export class DataMap extends Map {
    constructor(...args:any){
      super(...(args as []))
    }
    updateFromList(values:Array<any>, key:string='id'){
      const self = this;
      values.forEach((_:any)=>{
        self.set(_[key], _)
      })
    }
  }

I would classify this as a pretty simple object holding onto a map.  toJSON is defined, so how come I can't use an object?
** UPDATE **
I simplified the class base on @kissu 's comment.  Seems to be in the the right direction.  I tried the below but its not working.  Anyone know what the proper way to write / debug these PayloadPlugin's is?
// ./src/plugins/payload.ts
export default definePayloadPlugin(() => {
    definePayloadReducer('DataMap', (data) => {
        if(data instanceof DataMap){
            return Array.from(data.entries())
        }
    })
    definePayloadReviver('DataMap', (data:[any])=>{
        return new DataMap(data)
    })
})

Looks like its not hydrating properly:
nuxt.js?v=693fac13:98 [nuxt] error caught during app initialization Error: Unknown type DataMap
    at hydrate (parse.js?v=693fac13:105:13)
    at hydrate (parse.js?v=693fac13:60:40)
    at hydrate (parse.js?v=693fac13:60:40)
    at hydrate (parse.js?v=693fac13:125:19)
    at hydrate (parse.js?v=693fac13:125:19)
    at hydrate (parse.js?v=693fac13:125:19)
    at hydrate (parse.js?v=693fac13:60:40)
    at unflatten (parse.js?v=693fac13:132:9)
    at parse (parse.js?v=693fac13:16:9)
    at parsePayload (payload.js?v=693fac13:102:16)


Give a watch to this one: https://youtu.be/8w6ffRBs8a4

@kissu - updated based on the video you linked.  Any ideas on why the plugin might not be working?
